# Visitor Identifier & enableTracking

Tags: xdb

Currently I have two projects with different Analytics issues.
The first project do not contain `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` in layout. So if I open Experience profile I still can see contacts but If I try to get more info about contact I see an error like:
[image]

The second project missing `enableTracking="true"` in site definition config section. But I can not to find any issues with it. But I think that it affects something.

My question is how these two things (`@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` and  `enableTracking="true"`) affect to process of collecting contact information?

What consequences does missing `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()`line have?

What consequences does missing `enableTracking="true"`configuration attribute have?

Answer (score 1):

Missing @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() will not set a cookie on the visiting client, so every request will be identified as a new visitor

Missing enabletracking=true will have no consequences, since true is the default.